# reusing subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a query which works just fine, however I use the same subquery twice in it. I would like to know if there is a way to reuse this subquery. Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT homeworks.*
FROM homeworks
INNER JOIN homework_messages ON homeworks.id = homework_messages.homework_id
WHERE homework_messages.message_type = 'submit'
  AND homework_messages.created_at::date <= (CURRENT_DATE - '5 days'::interval)
  AND (
    (
      SELECT MAX(homework_messages.created_at) FROM homework_messages
      WHERE homework_messages.homework_id = homeworks.id AND homework_messages.message_type != 'submit'
    ) < homework_messages.created_at 
    OR 
    (
      SELECT MAX(homework_messages.created_at) FROM homework_messages
      WHERE homework_messages.homework_id = homeworks.id AND homework_messages.message_type != 'submit'
    ) IS NULL
  )
GROUP BY homeworks.id
```

As you can see I repeat these lines twice:

```
(
  SELECT MAX(homework_messages.created_at) FROM homework_messages
  WHERE homework_messages.homework_id = homeworks.id AND homework_messages.message_type != 'submit'
)
```

I tried to use WITH clause and it seems it doesn't suit this problem, or maybe I'm using it wrong. Anyway thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you use a PL/PgSQL function?

Comment: If you check the execution plan I would bet the statement is only actually executed once; consider using it in a *lateral join*

Comment: Unrelated, but the `distinct` as uses is a code smell. You can probably get rid of that, by turning that inner join into an `exists` condition.

Comment: `homeworks.id` is likely the primary key, otherwise PG would generate a functional dependence error.  That also suggests `DISTINCT` is not required due to `GROUP BY homeworks.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `cross join lateral` suggestion. I have not delved into your business logic and just tried to keep it equivalent.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT homeworks.*
FROM homeworks
INNER JOIN homework_messages ON homeworks.id = homework_messages.homework_id
cross join lateral ( -- your subquery follows
  SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at FROM homework_messages
  WHERE homework_id = homeworks.id AND message_type != 'submit'
) as lat
WHERE homework_messages.message_type = 'submit'
  AND homework_messages.created_at::date <= (CURRENT_DATE - '5 days'::interval)
  AND (lat.created_at < homework_messages.created_at OR lat.created_at IS NULL)
GROUP BY homeworks.id;
```